# Render template directive after click event - AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive that should show an image after clicking on the link of that image with in the **template directive**. I want to be able to render the template once the user click on that image. How can I achieve that with a directive?

**Directive Usage:**

> `<a href="img/img.jpg" gallery><img src="img/img.jpg"></a>`

**Directive simplified**

```
app.directive('gallery', function() {

     return {
        scope: {},
        templateUrl: '/templates/gallery.html', // to Render after Click
        link: function(scope,el,attr) {

             el.click(function(e) {

                 e.preventDefault();
                 // How can I render here the template?
             });

        }
     }

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the ng-if directive triggered by a scoped variable which is changed after the click.
It's not performing the rendering later, which I'm not sure is possible without a great hassle.

But it doesn't cost in performance or add the containing element until it's resolved truthy.

```
link: function(scope,el,attr) {
    scope.templateState = false;
    el.click(function(e) {
         e.preventDefault();
         scope.templateState = true; // Change state
    });

}
```

And the template (containing element):

```
<div ng-if="templateState"></div>
```

I'll try to elaborate if it's unclear.

Comment: Thanks for your answer it may make sense, but I would like keep the a single directive on the element, without add complexity with others directives.

Comment: You are keeping a single directive on the original element. 

I meant for the ng-if to be added on the containing element which is the first inside the template.
I don't think you'll get away easier than that.

Comment: Ok i got it, I'll try that and I let you know the response thanks a lots.

Comment: Yea sure, would be interesting to know if you found any faults doing this.